# checking if value in dropdown list

Tags: jquery, list, select

I have the list:

```
<td id="filter_analyst">
<select>
    <option>mike1</option>
    <option>mike2</option>
    <option>mike3</option>
</select>
```

and i'm trying to check if some value exist:

```
var name = 'mike1';
alert(name);
var t = ($("#filter_analyst").find("[value='"+name+"']").length) > 1;
alert(t);
```

But getting false...

Am I doing something wrong?
http://jsfiddle.net/BFMD4/32/

Thanks in advance!

Comment: there's no `value` attribute...

Comment: also your logic to check if the name exists is actually checking to see if more than one of that name exists, you should use > 0

Answer (score 2):

The `value` is not the label of the option but the HTML tag within the `<option>`.

See this working example: http://jsfiddle.net/ZZaSW/

[EDIT] Another example more like your HTML (but a `<td>` without a table doesn't work so I've put a `<div>` for the example).

Here is the HTML:

```
<div id="filter_analyst">
    <select>
        <option value="mike1">mike1</option>
        <option>mike2</option>
        <option>mike3</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

And the js:

```
var t = $('#filter_analyst').find('option[value=mike1]').length > 0;
```

Comment: he wants by name  not by value !

Comment: it's correct html syntax, so he should change his html according to proper standart

Comment: @Jmax  If value will be coming as dynamic as an function argument then how can i make the above solution work ? The following does not work E.g :: function (strVal){var t = $('#filter_analyst').find('option[value=strVal]').length > 0; }

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/BFMD4/37/

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td id="filter_analyst">
            <select id="dropdown1">
                <option value='mike1'>mike1</option>
                <option>mike2</option>
                <option>mike3</option>
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
```

```
//Find by value
alert($("#dropdown1 option[value='mike1']").length);
//Find by text
alert($("#dropdown1 option:contains('mike1')").length);
```

In your original example, the td selector was not working because it was missing the wrapping table and tr tags.

Answer (score 0):

**working answer**

http://jsfiddle.net/BFMD4/45/

```
var name = 'i am mike1';
var t = $("#filter_analyst select").find("option").filter(function (){return $(this).text()==name }).length
alert(t);
```

Comment: @Reigel , `option:contains` its fine ( ive added `option` prefix)

Comment: That's a better shot. Here is the working jsfiddle btw: http://jsfiddle.net/xX3nw/

Comment: no! it's not... ;) `:contains()` will also return true for `I am mike1`... not good... isn't it?

Comment: @RoyiNamir: That's why I posted it as a comment of your answer but you could have posted it by yourself. This is a better way to show that it works (or not).

Comment: @Reigel: thanks for the explanation of why `:contains()` is a bad choice

Comment: @Mike , Ive edited and tested. this is the working final solution

Answer (score 0):

[Try demo](http://jsfiddle.net/BFMD4/38/)

```
var name = 'mike1';
var t = $("#filter_analyst select").find("option").filter("[text='" + name + "']").length >= 1;
alert(t);
```

Comment: You're right! With single words this work, but with a sentence you have to have ''. Try this http://jsfiddle.net/BFMD4/44/

Answer (score 0):

Try This
HTML as below

```
<select id="ddltest">
<option value="mike1">mike1</option>
<option value="mike2">mike2</option>
<option value="mike3">mike3</option>
```

JS Code as Below,

```
 var name = 'mike1';
            var t = $("#ddltest option:contains(" + name + ")").val();
            if (t !== undefined) {
                alert(t);
            } else {
                alert('Name not existing');
            }
```